# Ordering variables in a column of a df does not work when render reactable

Tags: html, r, reactable

I have a column in my data where the variables are not in the correct order and I need to change them in order to visualize the render correctly.

I am giving a reproducible example so that it is easier to understand:

```
library(reactable)
library(dplyr)

species <- c("setosa", "versicolor")
df <- iris %>%
  filter(Species %in% species)
numbers <- c( 100, 300,400, 50)
type <- rep(numbers, times=25)
df1 <- df %>% mutate(type = type)
df2 <- df1 %>%
mutate(species_type= case_when(Species == "setosa" ~ paste0(Species,": ", type),
                               Species == "versicolor" ~ paste0(type,": ", Species),
                               TRUE ~ Species ))
columns <- list(colDef(minWidth = 140), colDef(align = "center"))
columns <- setNames(columns, names(df2)[2:3])
reactable(df2, columns = columns)
```

I need the species_type in the table rendered to be ordered so that the species_type with 50 in it comes first, I have a pre-computed dataframe where the order is similar to the example above.however i tried to arrange befofe render but I still get the wrong order in the table.
how could I do it? I tried arranging thanks a lot!

Comment: It should work if you arrange `df2` by `type` and not `species_type`.  `df2 %>% arrange(type)`.

Comment: In case your original `data.frame` doesn't contain the bare values as in `type`, you can recreate them by using `readr::parse_number(species_type)`.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to re-arrange (not sure why this does not work for you) your data by `type` before passing it to `reactable`.

Note: I simplified the example data a bit by keeping only the `Species` column from `iris` and only four rows per `Species`.

```
library(reactable)
library(dplyr)

species <- c("setosa", "versicolor")
df <- iris[c(1:4, 51:54), ] %>%
  select(Species) %>%
  filter(Species %in% species)
numbers <- c(100, 300, 400, 50)
type <- rep(numbers, times = 2)
df1 <- df %>% mutate(type = type)
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(species_type = case_when(
    Species == "setosa" ~ paste0(Species, ": ", type),
    Species == "versicolor" ~ paste0(type, ": ", Species),
    TRUE ~ Species
  ))

columns <- list(colDef(minWidth = 140), colDef(align = "center"))
columns <- setNames(columns, names(df2)[2:3])

df2 %>%
  arrange(type) %>%
  reactable(, columns = columns)
```

[image]

A second option would be to use the `defaultSorted` argument to sort by `type`:

```
reactable(df2, columns = columns, defaultSorted = "type")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! in the end I did it per type!